# Function operators and environments

Tags: r, functional-programming

Alright stackies,

I've been reading [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html) and have really found it helpful. I'm at a spot where I really don't understand R's behavior in the example:

```
dot_every <- function(n, f) {
  i <- 1
  function(...) {
    if (i %% n == 0) cat(".")
    i <<- i + 1
    f(...)
  }
}
```

So the idea here is that we are to display a period every nth iteration of the function. What I don't understand is how the value of i is being maintained through multiple calls of `dot_every` in a functional. I understand that `<<-` moves up through environments searching for something named `i` and then replaces with `i+1`. I would have thought that something like this:

`x <- lapply(1:20, dot_every(10, runif))`

would garbage collect that `i` for each iteration in `lapply` and thus never increment it. My intuition is that it would work like this:

```
for(i in 1:20){
  dot_every(10, runif)(i)
}
```

Which does seem to be calling `dot_every`, garbage collecting `i`, and thus not displaying anything. What's different about using the functional than the for loop in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case (with the `lapply`) you are calling `dot_every()` only once, and then using the resulting function on every element in `1:20`. In the second case, you are calling `dot_every()` in every pass through the loop, and then using the resulting function just once. To see this, insert the line:

```
cat("!")
```

as the first line in the definition of `dot_every()`. Then:

```
> x <- lapply(1:20, dot_every(10, runif))
!..
```

but

```
> for(i in 1:20) dot_every(10,runif)(i)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Ahhh... that mostly makes sense. So the environment that `dot_every` creates isn't closed until `lapply` is done executing? That would make sense to me in terms of how each call is able to affect `i`

Comment: Each call to `dot_every()` creates a new closure, which exists until the function created by `dot_every()` goes out of scope.